# Persistent memcached in PHP - server pool growing until curr_connections 10

Tags: php, memcached, libmemcached

I have a problem with Memcached persistence in PHP. Memcached lib returns empty `getServerList()` until there are 10 concurrent connections. Couldn't find sensible explanation of that, but found people with the same problem (without solution).

My example:

```php
class Cache {

    protected $memcached;

    public function __construct($cache_name) {
        $instance_name = 'persistent-' . $cache_name;
        $this->memcached = new Memcached($instance_name);
        $server_count = count($this->memcached->getServerList());
        echo '[MC] Server count of ', $instance_name, ': ', $server_count, PHP_EOL;

        if (0 == $server_count) {
            $servers = array(array("localhost","16586"),array("localhost","16587"));
            echo '[MC] Adding servers: ', json_encode($servers), PHP_EOL;
            // options don't change anything in my case
            $this->memcached->setOptions(array(
                Memcached::OPT_DISTRIBUTION => Memcached::DISTRIBUTION_CONSISTENT,
                Memcached::OPT_LIBKETAMA_COMPATIBLE => true
            ));
            $this->memcached->addServers($servers);
        }

        $stats = $this->memcached->getStats();
        foreach($stats as $server => $data){
            echo '[MC] Stats of ', $server, ' curr_connections: ', $data['curr_connections'], ' total_connections: ', $data['total_connections'], PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

    public function get($key) {
        echo '[MC] Server for key: ', $key, ' is ', json_encode($this->memcached->getServerByKey($key)), PHP_EOL;
        $ret = $this->memcached->get($key);
        echo '[MC] Getting ', $key, ' with result: ', $ret, PHP_EOL;
        return $ret;
    }

    public function set($key, $data, $timeout = 0) {
        echo '[MC] Set of ', $key, ' with data: ', $data, PHP_EOL;
        return $this->memcached->set($key, $data, $timeout);
    }
}

$cache = new Cache('instance');

$ret = $cache->get('something');

if(empty($ret)) {
    $cache->set('something', true);
}
```

What I expect from this code is single `addServers` run after connections are established.

Fresh run (after memcached/apache restart) shows:

```
// first run
[MC] Server count of persistent-instance: 0
[MC] Adding servers: [["localhost","16586"],["localhost","16587"]]
[MC] Stats of localhost:16586 curr_connections: 5 total_connections: 6
[MC] Stats of localhost:16587 curr_connections: 5 total_connections: 6
[MC] Server for key: something is {"host":"localhost","port":16587,"weight":1}
[MC] Getting something with result: 
[MC] Set of something with data: 1

// second
[MC] Server count of persistent-instance: 0
[MC] Adding servers: [["localhost","16586"],["localhost","16587"]]
[MC] Stats of localhost:16586 curr_connections: 6 total_connections: 7
[MC] Stats of localhost:16587 curr_connections: 6 total_connections: 7
[MC] Server for key: something is {"host":"localhost","port":16587,"weight":1}
[MC] Getting something with result: 1

// up to 6th call curr_connections are growing and still adding servers to pool
[MC] Server count of persistent-instance: 0
[MC] Adding servers: [["localhost","16586"],["localhost","16587"]]
[MC] Stats of localhost:16586 curr_connections: 10 total_connections: 11
[MC] Stats of localhost:16587 curr_connections: 10 total_connections: 11
[MC] Server for key: something is {"host":"localhost","port":16587,"weight":1}
[MC] Getting something with result: 1

// 7th+ call finally with expected result
[MC] Server count of persistent-instance: 2
[MC] Stats of localhost:16586 curr_connections: 10 total_connections: 11
[MC] Stats of localhost:16587 curr_connections: 10 total_connections: 11
[MC] Server for key: something is {"host":"localhost","port":16587,"weight":1}
[MC] Getting something with result: 1
```

Am I missing something? What's happening?

My config:

- Ubuntu 13.04
- Apache 2.2.22
- Memcached server 1.4.14 (4 instances)
- libmemcached 1.0.8
- PHP 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.3
- Memcached lib for PHP [latest](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/php5-memcached).

## UPDATE 2014.04.22

The problem still exists on my latest config:

- Xubuntu 13.10 (kernel 3.11.0-19)
- Apache 2.4.6
- Memcached 1.4.14
- libmemcached 1.0.8
- PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.3
- Memcached lib for PHP 2.1.0

Comment: Thanks for not helping! :P Got cool badge: "Tumbleweed" - `bronze badge: Asked a question with no votes, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week`..

Comment: Could you add to log persistent_id ('persistent-' . $cache_name) ?

Comment: Added. What is this for? :)

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure I see what your "problem" is.
Each of your Apache PHP "servers" (i.e. child workers) when they start have not yet connected to memcache - so each needs to initialise a connection - they each do... once.

Now each worker has a server list.

if you were to query it a 2nd time - you would "see" the server list..
but you have a cache object that I'm presuming you only instantiate once. So you never call it a second time, so it would never attempt to call the getServers a second time... so you would never see a "here is the server list".

Do I have that correctly?

If so, it is one of the common problems/misconceptions about "singletons". The most important question you always need to ask about singletons is "How many of them are there" - because they are only "single" in the context they control.... but as in this case - other external factors may make more of them.
In this case there is one per PHP instance.... but your apache makes *multiple* PHP instances - so there will be one each - and those share *nothing*, so each needs its own globals, its own persistent connection to database, persistent connection to memcache etc etc.

Very happy to be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php-fpm (or a similar config with Apache), each php child will create its own persistent connection to memcache. So if php-fpm is configured to create 10 child, your log output makes fully sense :-)